# Read Posix System Call

Tags: c, posix

I'm trying to print out the contents of a file, however the program will pause at the read() function and won't continue until I hit the enter key. Once the enter key is pressed, nothing is printed to the terminal. The rest of the program is not shown, but here is the method that is causing the issue.

```
{
char buff[1024];
ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
int readFile, error;
if((readFile = open(file,O_RDONLY)<0))
   {
        printf("can't open %s\n",file);
        error = errno;
        return -1;
   }
do{
        memset(buff,0,1024);
        if((bytesRead=read(readFile,buff,1024))==-1)
        {
            printf("error reading file");
            error = errno;
            printf("%d",error);
        }
        else
            printf("%s",buff);
   }while(bytesRead==1024);
   printf("\n");
   close(readFile);
   return 1;
}
```

Alternatively, if I change the read() function to pread(file,buff,1024,0) it throws an illegal seek 29 error.

Comment: Can you please add a `\n` to the end of your `printf("error reading file");`? Without it the message may not make it out of the `printf` line buffer, so you wouldn't be seeing it appear, making you wonder what's going on.

Comment: I tried it but still no dice, thanks though.

Comment: Oh god. `if((readFile = open(file,O_RDONLY)<0))`. This will set `readFile` to `0` or `1` only (More likely `0` - stdin). ***EDIT:*** Bump the `<0` right, between the `))`. The seek error is because you can't seek stdout or stdin.

Comment: Just put your assignment statements on separate lines from your `if`s from now on.  I don't understand why people try to cram so much into one line.  It's harder to read and it causes a lot of typo-like mistakes, like the one in the question.  Whoever is teaching people to use this kind of syntax should not be teaching.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the enter key should not effect the read call unless you are reading from stdin (standard input).  In that case, the input you provided - whitespace - may be printed out in the `printf("%s", buff);` call.  If you could include some steps on how you found out that this is the method causing the issue or how you found out that it pauses at the read line (and if you are reading from `/dev/stdin`), it may be easier to help.

Consequently, the same printf call may never return, if the bytes read do not contain a null and the bytesRead count is 1024 - the string in buff would not be null terminated.  You can fix this by either doing `buff[1023] = '\0';` or by setting a length limit in the printf call like `printf("%.1024s", buff);`

Comment: Well I changed the do while loop to only contain memset and the read() function, and the program still behaves the same. While removing the do while loop eliminates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
do{
        memset(buff,0,1024);
        if((bytesRead=read(readFile,buff,1024))==-1)
        {
            printf("error reading file");
            error = errno;
            printf("%d",error);
        }
        else
            printf("%s",buff);
   }while(bytesRead==1024);
```

Your loop isn't correct. It assumes that `read()` fills the buffer; it fails if the file isn't a multiple of 1024 bytes; it corrupts `errno` before printing it; and it does unnecessary `memset()` operations. Honey it's a mess. It should look like this:

```
while ((bytesRead=read(readFile, buff, sizeof buff)) > 0)
{
    printf("%.*s", bytesRead, buff);
}
if (bytesRead < 0)
{
    error = errno;  
    perror("error reading file");
    printf("errno=%d\n",error);
}
```